# C# Hashtable not getting assigned a string

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I recently came across this problem regarding hashtable and was wondering if anyone knows why. See  the small code example below and the output.

```
Hashtable temp = new Hashtable();
temp["a"] = ("100")[0].ToString();
temp["b"] = "1";

if(temp["a"] == "1")
  Response.Write("1");
else
  Response.Write("0");

if(temp["b"] == "1")
  Response.Write("1");
else
  Response.Write("0");
```

Output is "01". Why isn't it "11"? temp["a"] is getting assigned a string, so why isn't that actually happening?

Anyone who can explain this to me or point me to an article that may contain an explanation would be a great help. It's been bugging me.

Thanks!

Comment: You're comparing strings by reference.  Use generics.

Comment: or cast prior to comparison. but generics would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Use of generics have the same output. I'm not looking to a solution to get it to work I'm looking for an answer why it doesn't work. I shouldn't need to cast it before comparison. It's being assigned a string.

Comment: Also you should be using a `Dictionary` not `HashTable` unless there is a good reason not to....

Comment: @Aomine That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

`if(temp["a"] == "1")`

is comparing the hashtable object to the string "1" which is comparing an object to a string. The object's root type may be string, but the comparison won't know that.

If you call

`if(temp["a"].ToString() == "1")`

instead, it should work.

Another option would be to use a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` generic which will return object type `TValue` instead of an object when you call `temp["a"]`

`Dictionary<string,int> temp = new Dictionary<string,int>();`

Comment: How is if(temp["b"] == "1") any different? It doesn't need casting.

Comment: As @SLaks mentioned, because it is passing it by reference. Calling `("100")[0].ToString();` gives you a different memory refernce than `"1"` And when C# compares an object type, it uses memory locations not string values.

Comment: Essentially the compiler is smart so when you hardcode "1" in many different positions it will still point to the same location in memory. Look up string interning.

Comment: Try running this for an example. `(Object) 1 == (Object) 1;` Comparing an integer to another integer as an object doesn't compare the actual values, but instead compares the memory locations. Base types like int, string, bool, etc have comparison features built in that dictate how to compare two objects by value instead of by reference. You can even overload these and specify your own equality comparers on your own classes to dictate how to compare two objects of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

`((object)"1") == "1"[0].ToString()` evaluates to `False` because the two objects have different addresses. Since you're using a non-generic Hashtable class, `temp["a"]` is cast as an object, so it's doing that same comparison.

C# goes out of its way to make `string == string` work nicely (unlike Java), but it can't do that when it doesn't know you've got a string on both sides.

As other people have mentioned, you're better off using a generic class like Dictionary to maintain the strong typing of strings, but another approach would be to use `.Equals()` instead of `==`. Or manually cast the value as a string before using `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the comparison checks for **reference equality**, not **content equality**, because the left side has type **object**.

`temp["a"]` contains a reference to a string "1" on the heap which is created at runtime, which by definition IS NOT the same object in memory as the **interned** string "1" that it is being compared with. So it runs the else-part.

`temp["b"]` contains a reference to the **interned** string "1", which by definition IS the same object in memory as the **interned** string "1" that it is being compared with. So it runs the if-part.

For more info, look up "string interning".